# Reducing execution time Python

Tags: python, list, tree

given that I have a list like this (river discharge tree):
String type (11 elements).

`From;To
 1;2
 2;3
 5;4
 3;4
 4;-999
 9;6
 6;5
 10;7
 8;7
 7;5`

If you imagine it as a tree, it should be like (direction from top to bottom):

```
1   9  8  10
|   |   \/
2   6   7
|    \ /
3    5
|  /
4
|
```

I just want to expand the list so I would have all the combinations like

`From;To
 1;2
 2;3
 5;4
 3;4
 4;-999
 9;6
 6;5
 10;7
 8;7
 7;5
 1;3
 1;4
 6;4
 9;4
 9;5
 7;4
 8:4
 8:5
 10:5
 10:4`

There must be connection in the tree and the order must be from top to bottom.

What is the best way to do this?
I wrote a code for this but this would take me about 6 days of executing for 6000 rows.

```
should_restart = False
for b in range(1, lengthchange):
    row1 = str(tree[b])
    position2 = row1.find(delimeter)
    position3 = row1.find(end)
    from1 = (row1[0:position2])
    to1 = row1[position2+1:position3]
    for c in range(1, lengthchange):
        row2 = str(tree[c])
        position4 = row2.find(delimeter)
        position5 = row2.find(end)
        from2 = (row2[0:position4])
        to2 = row2[position4+1:position5]
        if to1 == from2 and not to2 == "-999":
            append1 = str(from1)+";"+str(to2)+"\n"
            seen = set(tree)
            if append1 not in seen:
                seen.add(append1)
                tree.append(append1)
                should_restart = True
                count_test = count_test+1
                print(count_test)
                lengthchange = len(tree)
```

Could you check my code and give me some advices?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What about 2;2, 3;3 and 3;2? Do you want **all** combinations including those?

Comment: Hi, I actually need 1;1 2;2 3;3 and 4;4 but I have another loop for this already.
3;2 is not right because the river cannot flow backwards.

Comment: Oh, wait, so your two lists, `from=[1, 2, 3]` and `to=[2,3,4]` are actually one set?

Comment: It is actually one list, yes one set.

Comment: Hmm, I wish Adi C hadn't deleted their answer. It was the right direction: `itertools.combinations(rivers, 2)` will give an iterator (of ~18m combinations) as you describe.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Just mind that `itertools.combinations(rivers, 2)` will omit the solutions `(1,1)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,3)`, and `(4,4)` which the OP asks for.

Comment: @YotamSalmon he said he already has a loop for that, but an iterator would be better... I'll add that

Comment: @PDUY The words "river discharge tree" makes me think you don't actually want all possible combinations of an input list. Are you really working with a tree, and have things like a branch where 1->2,3, but you wouldn't want (2,3) as an output?

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about now. Do rivers strictly branch (tree), strictly converge (upside down tree) or do both (graph)?

Comment: Thank you, a node can only flows to ONE another node. But many nodes can flow to a node.

Comment: Hi @temporalwolf, not that format i want but the results are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the key to doing this efficiently is ensuring we don't have to revisit nodes over and over again. We can do this by starting with the output and working our way back:

```
crivers = rivers[:]  # copy the rivers list, as this process is destructive
ckeys = set(river.split(";")[0] for river in crivers)  # make a set for O(1) lookup
result = {}
while crivers:
    for river in crivers[:]:
        key, value = river.split(";")
        if value in ckeys:
            continue  # skip rivers that are flowing into unprocessed rivers
        result[int(key)] = [int(value)] + result.get(int(value), [])
        ckeys.remove(key)
        crivers.remove(river)
```

If the `rivers` list is sorted properly, this is O(n), if it's not sorted (or, in the worst case, reverse sorted), it's O(n**2). "Sorted properly", in this case, means they are sorted from root to leaf in our upside down tree... as our processing order is: `4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 9, 10, 8, 1`

The final result is:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4, -999], 
 2: [3, 4, -999], 
 3: [4, -999], 
 4: [-999], 
 5: [4, -999], 
 6: [5, 4, -999], 
 7: [5, 4, -999], 
 8: [7, 5, 4, -999], 
 9: [6, 5, 4, -999], 
10: [7, 5, 4, -999]}
```

Which can be converted to your final format via:

```
fmt_lst = []
for key in result:
    for val in result[key]:
        fmt_lst.append("%s;%s" % (key, val))

['1;2', '1;3', '1;4', '1;-999', 
 '2;3', '2;4', '2;-999', 
 '3;4', '3;-999', 
 '4;-999', 
 '5;4', '5;-999', 
 '6;5', '6;4', '6;-999', 
 '7;5', '7;4', '7;-999', 
 '8;7', '8;5', '8;4', '8;-999', 
 '9;6', '9;5', '9;4', '9;-999', 
 '10;7', '10;5', '10;4', '10;-999']
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide a specific example... it's totally unclear what you are asking for... you have a list which you want to expand to all combinations, but not certain combinations, without any specifics on which should or should not be excluded?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope I get a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You are the best. It is working very fast, but unfortunately still doesn't work with the big list (6000 elements). Im trying to find why.
It just gave me:
{1: [2], 
 2: [3], 
 3: [4], 
 4: [5], 
 5: [6], 
 6: [7], 
 ....

Comment: I would guess the formatting is not the same. Can you pastebin the file?

Comment: it works fine for me if I remove the `From;To` line by only processing `rivers[1:]` where `rivers = pastebin_string.split("\n")` - `result` has 6000 items and there are 8.4m flow tuples. -- the `fmt_lst` object is 72.5MB of strings